# polling a database in a web server using a java application

Tags: java, php, sql, netbeans-7

i am trying to poll a database in a server and check if any new records are added, and if any i'm going to send a http request to the java application with the new record.

This is the GET request:

```
public class PHPDataChecker implements Runnable {
public static String output;
public void run(){
  try {
    URL url = new URL("http://taxi.net/login.php");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

    if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        (conn.getInputStream())));


    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    conn.disconnect();

  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

  } catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

  }

}
}
```

I'm using a scheduler and here is that code:

```
public class Main {
 private static boolean canStop=false;
public static void stopPHPDataChecker() {
    canStop=true;
}
public static void runnner() {
    // Setup a task for checking data and then schedule it
    PHPDataChecker pdc = new PHPDataChecker();
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    final ScheduledFuture<?> pdcHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(pdc, 0L, 10L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);// Start schedule

    scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
            System.out.println(">> TRY TO STOP!!!");
            pdcHandle.cancel(true);
            Main.stopPHPDataChecker();
            System.out.println("DONE");
        }

    }, 10L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    do {
        if (canStop) {
            scheduler.shutdown();
        }
    } while (!canStop);

    System.out.println("END");
}
```

another two programs to periodically poll it

RunMain.java:

```
public class RunMain implements Runnable {
 public void run(){
     Main m=new Main();
     m.runnner();
 }}
```

checkSchedule.java:

```
public class checkSchedule {
public static void main(String[] args) {
RunMain m = new RunMain();
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
final ScheduledFuture<?> pdcHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(m, 0L, 10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 }
}
```

This doensn't poll the database correctly is there anything wrong with the codings ?

this is the output i see in the nebeans IDE

> Output from Server .... 
>   {"return":"0"}
>   Output from Server ....
>  
>   {"return":"0"}
>
> > TRY TO STOP!!!
> >     DONE 
> >     END 
> >     TRY TO STOP!!! 
> >     DONE 
> >     END 
> >     TRY TO STOP!!! 
> >     DONE 
> >  
> >     END 
> >     TRY TO STOP!!! 
> >     DONE 
> >     END 
> >     TRY TO STOP!!! 
> >     DONE 
> >     END 
> >     TRY TO STOP!!! 
> >     DONE 
> >     END 
> >     TRY TO STOP!!! 
> >     DONE 
> >     END 
> >     TRY TO STOP!!! 
> >     DONE 
> >     END 
> >     TRY TO STOP!!! 
> >     DONE 
> >     END 
> >     TRY TO STOP!!! 
> >     DONE 
> >     END

Comment: When you say it doesn't do it correctly, what do you mean? Can you be more specific about what fails?

Comment: first,thank you for looking into this! well as you can see in the output i have shown Output from Server .... {"return":"0"} displays when it polls the database correctly through the php. but it happens only twice. i need it to happen continuously!